# How do you stop a `<p:poll interval='3' update='messages'/> tag after it updates messages once

Tags: jquery, jsf

How do you stop a `<p:poll interval='3' update='messages'/>` tag after it updates messages once and then restart it when you close messages?

Basically, I have this code:

```
<pe:layoutPane id="south" position="south" size="70">
   <p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" >  
      <script>
          jQuery('#messages').effect("pulsate", {times:5}, 1000 );
          jQuery('#messages').show();
       </script>
  </p:messages>
  <h:form id="pollF">
      <p:poll interval="10" listener="#{alarmsBean.checkAlarms()}" update=":messages" partialSubmit="true" widgetVar="poll"/>
  </h:form>
</pe:layoutPane>
```

It looks like Primefaces has the ability to call a poll.stop() and poll.start() but the problem is they showcase that functionality from onclick events on buttons.

My problem is that I don't have buttons here and do not want them. I want poll.stop() to get called when the messages tag gets updated once. And I want poll.start() to get called when the messages tag is closed.

Comment: it looks like this works:

    <script>poll.stop();</script>

Problem is I don't know how to call that conditionally when the page renders.

Comment: Does anyone have any thoughts or pointers on how to get this done?  Basically, I am trying to stop poll when messages is updated to prevent poll from overwriting messages after 10 seconds, since poll has update=":messages" and runs every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Include a outer panel and have it updated by poll. Then have your conditions with in the panel to stop the poll. Not sure how efficient is this but works.

```
<p:panel id="topPanel" style="border-color: white" > 
      <script>
            function stopMe(){
                new window().refresh();
                //poll.stop(); // I just refresh the window that stops the poll as I expereinced issue with pool.stop() while using dynamically
            }
          </script>
        <c:if test="${bean.var}"> //set a boolean after setting your message in your bean
           <script> stopMe() </script>
       </c:if>
        <p:poll interval="10" widgetVar="poll"  autoStart="true" update=":topPanel, :messages" />

</p:panel>
```